# JavaScript working with alert, not working without

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, alert

I'm wrote a script that updates a field in SharePoint list that works, but when I remove alert("test"); line it stops working. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });        

function loadConstants() {

    var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccess,
      error : onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data, request){
        var loginName = data.d.Title;

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("site name");
        var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list name');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);          

        ctx.load(this.oListItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {                                                   
                                                    this.oListItem.set_item('Read', loginName + '  ' + getTodayDate(););
                                                    }),  function (sender, args) { alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());});    

        //HERE IS THE ALERT:
        //alert("test");
        this.oListItem.update();            

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert("error");
    }
    function getTodayDate() {
        //code that gets today's date
        return today;
    }
}

</script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help with this issue!

Comment: They key part of `executeQueryAsync()` is `Async`. The `.update()` needs to be in the callback function you're passing. That's why there's a callback. ;-)

Comment: ...Any code that relies on the response from `executeQueryAsync()` needs to be invoked from within the callback function you're passing. The `alert()` makes it work because it blocks the `.update()` long enough for the response to return.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with JavaScript, can you please explain to me how I do that? Thank you!

Comment: I tried setTimeout, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that API, but it looks like you're passing two callbacks to `executeQueryAsync()`.

The first one is actually first passed to `Function.createDelegate()`. I assume that returns a new function. Anyway, the anonymous function you're passing to that seems to be used for the purpose of responding to the query. So any code that relies on the data returned should be placed in there
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });

```
function loadConstants() {

    var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccess,
      error : onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data, request){
        var loginName = data.d.Title;

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("site name");
        var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list name');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);          

        ctx.load(this.oListItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {                                                   
                                  this.oListItem.set_item('Read', loginName + '  ' + getTodayDate();

// run after the executeQueryAsync response arrives---vvvvvv
                                  this.oListItem.update();            

                                  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                                     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                                     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
                                  );
                              }),  
                              function (sender, args) { 
                                  alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
                              });    
    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert("error");
    }
    function getTodayDate() {
        //code that gets today's date
        return today;
    }
}
```

So now your `.update()` code won't be invoked until that callback fires in response to the query being returned.

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it inside, but it didn't work... It only works when .update is outside and there is an alert before it.

Comment: @Ekaterina: If you put `alert("test")` in the callback (at the top), do you see the alert?

Comment: Yes, I see the alert, but the item doesn't get updated.

Comment: Also if I add another alert after the update line, I see it also.

Comment: @Ekaterina: I'm not sure why that would be. Again, I don't know that API, but putting the `.update()` inside the callback basically accomplishes exactly what the `alert()` was accomplishing, except without blocking the UI.

Comment: @Ekaterina: What happens if you put the `.update()` before the `.set_item()`? And is there any other code that runs after the position where the `.update()` originally was?

Comment: If I put .update() before .set_item() nothing changes. Here is what I have after the .update():

Comment: ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

Comment: @Ekaterina: What is `this.onQuerySucceeded`? Does that have the same code as your anonymous function? Can you post the actual code?

Comment: I took code from here as a base code: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx) under updating list item with JavaScript.

Comment: I updated my question with the actual code.

Comment: @Ekaterina: Is the second `executeQueryAsync()` supposed to wait for the successful response from the first `executeQueryAsync()`? If so, remember, that any code that relies on the response from an "asynchronous" function must be placed in the callback. So if the second call needs to wait for the completion of the first, then it should be in the callback of the first,.

Comment: @Ekaterina: I updated my answer to move the rest of that code to the first `executeQueryAsync` callback.